# SQL Server Data Rows exception incorrect syntax

Tags: c#, sql-server, webforms

I am working on a function and getting an error that keeps pointing in the area where the DataTable object is getting declared but it is only giving the following error (see below). Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Code:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = ConfigManager.SqlConnection;

/// <summary>
/// Load Data Rows for Section Type ID
/// </summary>
public void LoadSectionTypeIDList()
{
     String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT section_type_id"
                + "FROM [claims_module].[dbo].[template_clob_gl]"
                + "ORDER BY section_type_id";
            
     SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, myConnection);
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     myAdapter.Fill(ds, "claims_module");

     DataTable dt = ds.Tables["claims_module"];
     SectionDropDownList.Items.Add("Select");
    
     foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
     {
         SectionDropDownList.Items.Add(r["section_type_id"].ToString());
     }
}
```

Error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: You need to add at least **one space** between the parts of your SQL statement! Right now, you're getting `SELECT DISTINCT section_type_idFROM ....` - add at least one space at the end of each of the string parts that make up your query!

Comment: Thank you @marc_s I realized it after a few more tries, fixed the spacing and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that it was a syntax error from missing spaces between the sql statement.  Once I fixed it, the statement ran and the list appeared.